# Keyboard for UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextview

To inherit style for all textViews in my app I did

```
UITextView.appearance().keyboardAppearance = .dark
```

The problem is when I enter the screen with textView my application quits unexpectedly, in log I see:

> *** Assertion failure in void PushNextClassForSettingIMP(id, SEL)(), /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3599.6.1/UIAppearance.m:760
>
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Please file a radar on UIKit if you see this assertion.'
>   *** First throw call stack:

Comment: "Please file a radar on UIKit if you see this assertion.'". Did you file a radar?

Comment: It is already in https://github.com/PSPDFKit-labs/radar.apple.com/tree/master/33846788-TextViewKeyboardAppearance